# How, exactly, is ! meant to be used with 7-zip CLI parameters?

Tags: windows, command-line, 7-zip, parameters

The `-i` and `-x` parameters of the [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) CLI interpet `!` in a special way.  Or at least it looks that way from [their](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/include.htm) [documentation](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/exclude.htm).  That documentation includes the following:

---

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> -i[<recurse_type>]<file_ref>
>
> <recurse_type> ::= r[- | 0]
> <file_ref> ::= @{listfile} | !{wildcard}
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> ```
>     <file_ref>
> ```
>
> Specifies filenames and wildcards, or a list file, for files to be
>   processed.
>
> ```
>     <file_ref> ::= @{listfile} | !{wildcard}
> ```
>
> **Examples**
>
> ```
> 7z a -tzip src.zip *.txt -ir!DIR1\*.cpp
> ```
>
> adds to src.zip archive all *.txt files from current directory and all
>   *.cpp files from directory DIR1 and from all it's subdirectories.

---

I haven't, however, found an explicit statement about how `!` is meant to be used.  It *seems* from the reference to `!{wildcard}` that `!` *might* indicate that `<file_ref>` contains wildcards.  I'm skeptical about that, however, because such an indicator seems unnecessary.

How, exactly, is `!` meant to be used with 7-zip CLI parameters?

Answer (score 4):

`7z` [Command Line Syntax](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/syntax.htm) essentially preserves some kind of [standard syntax key](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771080.aspx) of [Backus-Naur form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form):

```
Notation                           Description
Text without brackets or braces    Items you must type as shown
<Text inside angle brackets>       Placeholder for which you must supply a value
[Text inside square brackets]      Optional items
{Text inside braces}               Set of required items; choose one
Vertical bar (|)                   Separator for mutually exclusive items; choose one
Ellipsis (…)                       Items that can be repeated
```

As neither `@` nor `!` is enclosed in any brackets or braces, you need to use them *literally*:

- `@{listfile}`: Specifies *name of list file*. See [List file](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/syntax.htm#ListFile) description
- `!{wildcard}`: Specifies *wildcard* or *filename*

**Example**:

- `-i@c:\temp\abc.txt` means *include all files matching criteria **listed in**  the `c:\temp\abc.txt` file*
- `-i!c:\temp\abc.txt` means *include the **file** `c:\temp\abc.txt` **itself***.

Comment: Thanks for the references to the apparent syntax key.  That makes interpretation of the 7-zip documentation _much_ clearer.